# Why shouldn't we check the User object to check if user is online in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

The [official Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#always-check-if-the-user-is-logged-in) tells us the following:

```
// yay! Use this to see if the user is logged in
if (!$this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
    throw $this->createAccessDeniedException();
}

// boo :(. Never check for the User object to see if they're logged in
if ($this->getUser()) {

}
```

I've been using `$this->getUser()` up until now without problems, both to check if the user is online and to get the current logged in user, and just discovered that it is wrong. But what I can't find is why is it wrong to do so.

Can anyone tell or give an example where this would cause an issue? I don't see a problem, since it always returns `null`(converted from `anon.` as the docs say) if there is nobody logged in and the current logged in User class as an object, with access to its methods.

Comment: Maybe because there is always a user object ? "anon." is authenticated but has an AnonymousToken so he's not fully authenticated. It's just an idea...

Comment: It is, but calling it without anyone being logged in always returns null, so what's the problem in using it instead of the security authorization checker?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is caused by remember-me tokens.

The Symfony docs state this:

> Users who are logged in only because of a "remember me cookie" will
>   have IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED but will not have
>   IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY.

`$this->getUser()` will not make this distinction, so it's advisable to use the `authorization_checker`. For that reason it is my assumption that this recommendation is simply made to avoid potential issues which developers who aren't aware of this fact might run into.

Comment: Sounds to be the reason ! Nice catch

Comment: But $this->getUser() returns the current user for both remembered users and fully authenticated ones.

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc: Yep, and in most cases, it should be equivalent to using the `authorization_checker` method. In certain situations, however, that might not be the case, therefore the docs try and make people avoid this in the first place, specifically calling it bad practice.

Comment: Well it's not really bad practice, it just depends on the type of application you're building, I guess.

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc: Yep. Nothing bad about making developers do the thing that never fails instead of the thing that sometimes fails, though. :)

Comment: The real advantage is to protect certain parts of the application like billing, account settings, etc. If user is remembered but not fully authenticated, you can ask I'm to validate his password to make sure it's the legitimate account owner that is requesting the access. Amazon do this, you can add stuff to cart or wish list as a remembered user, but not checkout or consult order history